# Install virt-sysprep on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: vagrant, libvirt

I'm using vagrant with vagrant-libvirt and I want to create a package via the command-line:

```
vagrant package --output ubuntu14-base.box
```

I've got an error around virt-sysprep being absent (confirm after a search in the system). I tried install those packages, without success:

1. libguestfs0;
2. libguestfs-dev;
3. ubuntu-virt;
4. virt-top;
5. virt-what;
6. ruby-guestfs

But still, no `virt-sysprep` installed. Searching in the Googlesphere always come back to `libguestfs-tools-c` that is not available in Ubuntu.

Comment: `No such file or directory - virt-sysprep (Errno::ENOENT)`

Answer (score 6):

I found out that *libguestfs-tools* was available and solve all my problems. Don't know how I missed that one...

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libguestfs-tools`